# uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::UserAgent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am using the [UserAgent Gem](https://github.com/josh/useragent).

I have the following code in my view

```
<%= user_agent = {} %>
<% user_agent = UserAgent.parse(request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]) %>
App: <%= user_agent.application %> # Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:22.0)
Browser: <%= user_agent.browser %> # Firefox
Version: <%= user_agent.version %> # 22.0
Platform: <%= user_agent.platform %> # Macintosh
Mobile: <%= user_agent.mobile? %> # False
OS: <%= user_agent.os %> # OS X 10.8
```

And i am getting the following error.

> uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::UserAgent

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, UserAgent isn't a thing...

How did you implement the gem? If you are using bundler, make sure you included the gem in your gemfile. You may also need to require it, like (probably) `gem 'useragent', :require=>'useragent'`. If not, you may just need to require it somewhere, before you use it.

It might just not be available in the current namespace, for some weird reason, in which case you can use something like: `<% user_agent = ::UserAgent.parse(request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]) %>`.